# What's the longest known case of covid-19 infection?

Tags: covid-19

Recently it's been reported about a spanish politician who has been infected with covid-19 for over 5 weeks. Is this possible or does it have to be a re-infection? What's the longest known case of covid-19 infection?

Comment: possibly related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/have-cases-of-covid-19-virus-reactivation-been-noticed-in-countries-besides-ch

Comment: A link to an article about the Spanish politician (in English) would improve your question.

Comment: Does this refers only to the infection? regardless of the incubation period? or both together?

Answer (score 4):

From [Taiwan English News](https://taiwanenglishnews.com/man-spends-81-days-in-hospital-with-no-symptoms-of-covid-19/)

### Man spends 81 days in hospital with no symptoms of COVID-19

> A Taiwanese businessman who was put into a negative pressure isolation ward in January ,after breaching quarantine on his return from Wuhan, China, then testing positive for COVID-19, was finally released today, Taiwan’s Central Epidemic Command Center (CECC) confirmed.
>
> **....**
>
> On April 9, a member of the CECC specialist consultative group described the man’s case as the country’s most stubborn. The patient would return two negative tests in a row, then a positive. A few days later there would be another negative, then in recent days several weak positives in a row. It began to have an affect on the patient’s mental state, according to an article in Health and Hope
>
> **......**
>
> Health Minister and CECC head Chen Shih-chung (陳時中)  confirmed at a regular press conference today that the man had been discharged after an 81 day stay in isolation, and that he had been the longest hospitalized case in the country.

Eighty-one (81) days is the longest known case in Taiwan so far.